# flutter ios app crashes after firebase setup

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm trying to configure firebase for my flutter ios app, I have downloaded my `GoogleService-Info.plist` and added it to the `Runner/Runner` folder in Xcode. When running the app, I get this error

```
Configuring the default Firebase app...
    "signalStrengthChanged:info:",
    "cellChanged:cell:",
    "connectionStateChanged:connection:dataConnectionStatusInfo:",
    "carrierBundleChange:"
)
    "signalStrengthChanged:info:",
    "cellChanged:cell:",
    "connectionStateChanged:connection:dataConnectionStatusInfo:",
    "carrierBundleChange:"
)
    "signalStrengthChanged:info:",
    "cellChanged:cell:",
    "connectionStateChanged:connection:dataConnectionStatusInfo:",
    "carrierBundleChange:"
)
    "signalStrengthChanged:info:",
    "cellChanged:cell:",
    "connectionStateChanged:connection:dataConnectionStatusInfo:",
    "carrierBundleChange:"
)
Configured the default Firebase app __FIRAPP_DEFAULT.
Lost connection to device.
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d2161bb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c7b4735 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d215d29 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Runner                              0x0000000104014564 GADApplicationVerifyPublisherInitializedAnalyticsCorrectly + 263
    4   Runner                              0x0000000103fc40f8 GADStatusBarOrientation + 3141
    5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e42c4e1 _di<…>
Exited (sigterm)
```

Any Ideas what I might be missing?

Answer (score 3):

This issue is most likely due to missing content in the Info.plist, as it was for me.

Add the following to Info.plist

```
<key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
<string>ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~1458002511</string>
```

Be sure to replace `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~1458002511` with your AdMob ID.

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/quick-start

Answer (score 0):

Did you include `firebase_admob` in the `pubspec`? If yes you have to call the init method for this, or just simple remove this dependency if you're not using it.