# Error After Adding Firebase for iOS on Flutter App

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I added the Firebase files to my app but it crashes right after it opens because in the first screen I call `FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()`.

I tried this solution and added the file through Xcode but the app still crashing.
Solution: [flutter ios app crashes after firebase setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58410328/flutter-ios-app-crashes-after-firebase-setup)

This is, how my ìnfo.plist`looks like.

[image]

This is my `plist` file provided by Google;

[image]

The error I'm getting;

[image]

Error in text:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           20.1s
    path: satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en1
Configuring the default Firebase app...
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c7127e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff513fbb20 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c710bc +[NSException raise:format:] + 188
    3   Runner                              0x0000000102ea421a +[FIRApp configure] + 138
    4   Runner                              0x000000010349aa96 -[FLTCloudFirestorePlugin init] + 214
    5   Runner                              0x000000010349a894 +[FLTCloudFirestorePlugin registerWithRegistrar:] + 292
    6   Runner                              0x0000000102e4ada0 +[GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:] + 112
    7   Runner                        <…>
```

Comment: add some code of your first screen

Comment: First screen is basically calls a Firebase request to see if there is a `currentUser` using the app. Firestore doesn't work as expected and that's why it can't make the request to the `Firebase`.